# Deleting Rows in Torch Tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, tensor

I have a torch tensor as follows -

```
a = tensor(
[[0.2215, 0.5859, 0.4782, 0.7411],
[0.3078, 0.3854, 0.3981, 0.5200],
[0.1363, 0.4060, 0.2030, 0.4940],
[0.1640, 0.6025, 0.2267, 0.7036],
[0.2445, 0.3032, 0.3300, 0.4253]],  dtype=torch.float64)
```

If the first value of each row is less than 0.2 then the whole row needs to be deleted. Thus I need the output like -

```
tensor(
[[0.2215, 0.5859, 0.4782, 0.7411],
[0.3078, 0.3854, 0.3981, 0.5200],
[0.2445, 0.3032, 0.3300, 0.4253]],  dtype=torch.float64)
```

I have tried to loop through the tensor and append the valid value to a new empty tensor but was not successful. Is there any way to get the results efficiently?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Code**

```
a = torch.Tensor(
    [[0.2215, 0.5859, 0.4782, 0.7411],
    [0.3078, 0.3854, 0.3981, 0.5200],
    [0.1363, 0.4060, 0.2030, 0.4940],
    [0.1640, 0.6025, 0.2267, 0.7036],
    [0.2445, 0.3032, 0.3300, 0.4253]])

y = a[a[:, 0] > 0.2]
print(y)
```

**Output**

```
tensor([[0.2215, 0.5859, 0.4782, 0.7411],
        [0.3078, 0.3854, 0.3981, 0.5200],
        [0.2445, 0.3032, 0.3300, 0.4253]])
```

Comment: Any way to do it inplace?

Comment: The slicing operation returns a view of the tensor, so extra memory is not needed even if assigned to another variable. If you assign the result to itself (i.e `a = a[a[:, 0] > 0.2]`) the memory for the other data will be immediately garbage collected as if you did an in-place operation.