# Delete rows from values from a torch tensor (drop method in pytorch)

Tags: python, pytorch

Let's say I have a pytorch tensor

```py
import torch
x = torch.tensor([
    [1,2,3,4],
    [5,6,7,8],
    [9,10,11,12]
    ])
```

And I want to delete the row with values `[5,6,7,8]`. I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58530117/deleting-rows-in-torch-tensor) (which solves the problem by indexing), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73041897/searching-for-a-1d-torch-tensor-in-a-2d-torch-tensor) (which solves the problem by masking), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62372762/delete-an-element-from-torch-tensor)  and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69132963/delete-a-row-by-index-from-pytorch-tensor) (deleting rows knowing the index).

In my case, I know the values of the tensor I want to delete, but not the index, and the values should be the same in every column of the tensor.

I could try doing the masking in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73041897/searching-for-a-1d-torch-tensor-in-a-2d-torch-tensor) and then indexing the rows as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62372762/delete-an-element-from-torch-tensor), something like this:

```py
ind = torch.nonzero(torch.all(x==torch.tensor([5,6,7,8]), dim=0))
x = torch.cat((x[:ind],x[ind+1:]))
```

That works, but I'd like a cleaner solution than splitting the tensor and concatenating it again. Something similar to the [drop()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) method in pandas dataframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the torch.all with combination of ~ NOT (inversion of bits)to exclude the column(s) that does match with the given one. It is one line code without splitting the tensor.

```
import torch

x = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3 ,4],
                  [5, 6, 7 ,8],
                  [9, 10, 11 ,12],])

x = x[~torch.all(x == torch.tensor([5,6,7,8]), dim=1)]
```

The resulting tensor is as follows;

```
tensor([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
```

Comment: Nice, I knew there was a simpler option... Thanks!!